# Servise vs IntentService для проигрывания музыки

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, android-intent

Делаю плеер, который проигрывает музыку.

Что выбрать IntentService или Service?

Что обычно используется для такой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

IntentService - расширение Service, предназначенное для долгих задач (музыка - самое то). К IntentService можно будет отправлять намерения (интенты) - например, прервать исполнение или ускорить воспроизведение - это уже как Вы реализуете.

Т.е. IntentService - самое то, что надо.

Подробнее тут: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/intentservice.php

Comment: IntentServise не подходит для проигрывания музыки, т.к. криво работает startForeground(id,notification), предназнаеченной именно для этого. 

Ответ: простой Servise